# Are large char buffers OK to use in C

Tags: c

I need to store a 'large' file (say a little under 2mb) in memory and I want to know if it's OK to just use

```
char buffer[2048000];
```

Is there a better way to handle it? Any performance issues with using large char arrays?

Comment: Depends where you declare it, OS restrictions on segment size, (eg. stack), and the like.

Comment: "stack overflow" is not just the name of this site...

Comment: Really depending on your platform, project's linker definition, etc. You would probably need to allocate it in the data section (i.e., static and/or global) in most cases. And if it somehow works when allocated on the stack (i.e. non-static local), then you most certainly want to avoid initializing it at upon declaration (e.g., `char buffer[2048000] = {0};`).

Comment: Note that most non-trivial OS are quite happy to allocate an initial process thread stack limit of 2MB and larger, you just need to ensure that the loadable image requests it.  Linkers usually have an expicit command to set that size in the executable header.  Additional threads normally inherit the stack limit of that applied to the intial loader thread, but that can often be changed at thread creation.

Comment: this is all very well until the file gets to be a little over 2mb in size.

Comment: Well sure.  Obviously, If I was to do such a thing, I would double it and add the number I first thought of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there could be issues, most C implementations will allocate that buffer on the stack if it's a variable of automatic storage duration, and the amount of "stack memory" available for use can be surprisingly small.

Your best bet is to use `malloc` for anything larger than a few kilobytes. Just remember to call `free` at an appropriate point.

Making it `static` is another possibility or making it global *might* help.

Answer (score 4):

If you declare it in the global namespace, no problems. It's just a block of memory, so no performance issues whatsoever.

Within a function, the variable is going to be allocated on the stack, and you can easily run out of stack space. Avoid this approach. If you need it only in a local scope, allocate memory with `malloc` or use `mmap` to handle the file.

Comment: “global namespace” is a red herring. You should have said “static storage” which is the relevant attribute. You can have variables with block scope and static storage. Just declare them as `static`.

Comment: Indeed. This question is difficult to answer especially given the fact that the C standard doesn't mention a "stack". But, pedantry aside, this answers the question well.

Answer (score 3):

When you statically allocate the buffer in this way, you're asking the computer for 2048000 contiguous bytes free in memory.  That isn't the same as asking for 2048000 bytes of free memory, since it must *also* be contiguous.  You can therefore imagine that the larger the space to allocate is, the less likely you will find that amount of contiguous memory free.

The common approach is to use malloc to allocate the memory.  This gives the program a chance to check the return value and act on it in the case in which NULL is returned (no memory given).  This doesn't reduce the possibility of a memory problem from happening, but it also allows you, the programmer, to have more control in such a case.

In cases in which you need to allocate large amounts of memory (large enough that this could be an issue), one approach is to create a linked list of smaller char arrays.  When you reach the end of one array, you follow the linked list to the next array and continue reading.  This is best accompanied with a couple helper methods so the caller doesn't have to worry about these details.

This ensures that you don't need 2MB of contiguous memory but 10 contiguous arrays at 200 kb each, meaning they could potentially be in separate positions in memory.

In applications that pre-allocate memory used in the program (as in the case of games), the common approach is this, with multiple smaller allocated arrays in a linked list.  The buffer is also written to initially since the operating system has been known to allocate memory lazily and not actually allocate the memory until it is accessed for the first time, which as you can imagine can create problems when the memory is actually required by the program.  The big advantage in pre-allocating memory is that no new memory is usually required during the life of the program, and the entire linked list can be freed at the end without having to keep track of individual pointer allocations.

Comment: *Contiguous*. Pretty please?

Comment: @Bathsheba I know how it's spelled!  ... making corrections...   ._.

Comment: That is good advice if the program is running in a small, memory-constrained system. If the program is running in a typical OS environment on a typical PC, it would have at least 2 GiB of virtual address space to play with, so finding 2048000 bytes of contiguous virtual address space for the buffer wouldn't normally be a problem (unless it allocates lots of other big chunks of memory).

Comment: @IanAbbott You're probably right, and in fact the OP could probably get away with doing it as he is now, though the higher you go, the better it is to do it this way.

Answer (score 3):

You can allocate a buffer in 3 ways:

1) On the stack. This happens when you define a non-static array within function scope. The stack size depends on your compiler and architecture, but the rule of thumb that one should not try and allocate big buffers there.

2) On the heap (using `malloc`). You can safely allocate big buffers there.

3) In the program data segment. This happens when you define a static array in any scope. It's ok to allocate big arrays there as well.